# Evento OnConfiguring da classe de Contexto do Identity não dispara ao gravar um registro na tabela AspNetUsers

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

Estou utilizando o Identity no Asp.net core e meu contexto herda d e uma classe NetDevPackAppDbContext que é um assembly muito bacana criado pelo Eduardo Pires. Estou fazendo um override do evento "OnConfiguring" só que ele nunca dispara. No momento em que eu gravar um novo "User" preciso que esse evento seja disparado para que eu obtenha a string de conexão para eu gravar no banco correto, pois estou tratabalhando com múltiplos "tenants". Alguém sabe como resolver?

Obrigado!

Repositório do [NetDevPack](https://github.com/NetDevPack/Security.Identity)

Meu Contexto:

```
public  class UsersDbContext : NetDevPackAppDbContext 
{
    
    public UsersDbContext(DbContextOptions<NetDevPackAppDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
        if (_currentTenantRepository is not null)
        {
            
        }           
    }


    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        //Não dispara :(

        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);

    }
}
```

Factory:

```
public class UsersDbContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<UsersDbContext>
{               
    public UsersDbContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);        
        var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<NetDevPackAppDbContext>();
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));

        return new UsersDbContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
    }   
}
```